# How to get an array of attributes hashes from an array of records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to print all questions and status fields. 
How can I extract the required data in an array ?

This is my array : `@category_questions`

`[#<Question id: 38, user_id: 1, question: "hi", question_status: 1, created_at: "2013-06-04 18:32:28", updated_at: "2013-06-04 18:32:28">, #<Question id: 40, user_id: 1, question: "urll", question_status: 1, created_at: "2013-06-04 18:34:57", updated_at: "2013-06-04 18:34:57">, #<Question id: 41, user_id: 1, question: "urll", question_status: 1, created_at: "2013-06-04 18:35:31", updated_at: "2013-06-04 18:35:31">]`

I tried `@category_questions[iteration_number][:some field]` but it did not work.

Comment: your question is unclear. Do you mean "i want to get an array containing questions and statuses from an array of Question objects ?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an array of hashes:

```
@category_questions.map do |question| 
  {question: question.question, status: question.question_status} 
end
```

To get an array of arrays:

```
@category_questions.map {|question| [question.question, question.question_status] }
```

Comment: Consider directing to the [ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/info) or [rails](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby-on-rails/info) tag-wikis (or editing them) rather than writing your own on each question :)

Comment: @AndyHayden. Ok. I'm just a bit disappointed that `The well grounded rubyist` is not in any answers i've seen... It is perfect for beginners. Should i add it ? Then again, i cannot stress how much i LOVE poignant's guide, but pointing people in search of a quick overview of the language to this book is insane. The book is a piece of art in itself, and a very psychedelic one !

Comment: @m_x it's in the ruby tag-wiki :)